# Why is unique_ptr null?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, object-lifetime

In the code snippet below, the assertion in `foo` always fires.

Can anyone explain why `y` is a `nullptr`? It looks like a lifetime issue, i.e. `y` is destroyed between the calls to `put` and `get` but I don't really understand why.

What am I missing?

TIA

```
class Y
{
public:
    Y(const std::string& name) : m_name(name)
    {
    }

    const std::string& getName() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }

private:
    Y(const Y&);

    const std::string m_name;
};

void foo(std::unique_ptr<Y> y)
{
    if (y == nullptr)
    {
        // ALWAYS FIRES
        assert(false && "nullptr\n");
    }

    std::string name = y->getName();
    std::cout << "name: " << name << "\n";
}

class X
{
public:
    X() {}

    void put(std::unique_ptr<Y> y)
    {
        m_queue.push([&] { foo(std::move(y)); });
    }

    void get()
    {
        std::function<void()> func = m_queue.front();
        func();
    }

private:
    std::queue<std::function<void()>> m_queue;
};


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Y> y(new Y("fred"));
    X x;
    x.put(std::move(y));
    x.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void put(std::unique_ptr<Y> y)
{
    m_queue.push([&] { foo(std::move(y)); });
}
```

Here, you push a lambda that contains a reference to the local variable `y`. The moment you leave `put`, the local variable is destroyed, and the lambda contains a dangling reference. Any further behavior is undefined.

You would need to capture the local variable by moving it into the lambda, but that is quite advanced, and also insufficient, because `std::function` cannot hold move-only function objects. The easiest way to solve this is to switch from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` and capturing by value in the lambda.

Answer (score 4):

```
void put(std::unique_ptr<Y> y)
{
    m_queue.push([&] { foo(std::move(y)); });
}
```

In this function, `y` is a local variable which gets destroyed when it goes out of scope. The local variable is captured (*by reference*), by the lambda, doesn't exist by the time when it is executed — it is pointing to nothing/null/garbage/whatever, as the `y` has been already destroyed.

Comment: Your `push()` shouldn't compile - `function` must be copyable.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is two fold.  First, you are capturing by reference in a lambda whose lifetime (and the lifetime of its copies) exceeds the current local scope.  Don't do that.  Only use `[&]` if your lambda (and all copies) will not be copied out of the lifetime of the local scope.

The naive answer is to then do a `[=]` or `[y]`, but you cannot copy a unique pointer.

In C++14, you can do `[y=std::move(y)]` which moves the `y` into the lambda capture.  However, a lambda that has captured a `unique_ptr` by-value cannot be copied.  And `std::function` can only store invokable, destroyable and copyable objects.

A solution to this would be to wait for a move-only `function` (which I think is coming down the pipe -- I've seen at least an informal proposal), or roll your own.

```
template<class Sig>
struct unique_function;
namespace details {
  template<class Sig>
  struct i_uf_impl;
  template<class R, class...Args>
  struct i_uf_impl<R(Args...)> {
    virtual ~i_uf_impl() {}
    virtual R invoke(Args&&...) = 0;
  };
  template<class Sig, class F>
  struct uf_impl;
  template<class R, class...Args>
  struct uf_impl<R(Args...):i_uf_impl<R(Args...)>{
    F f;
    virtual R invoke(Args&&...args) override final {
      return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  };
  template<class...Args>
  struct uf_impl<void(Args...):i_uf_impl<void(Args...)>{
    F f;
    virtual void invoke(Args&&...args) override final {
      f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
  };
}
template<class R, class...Args>
struct unique_function<R(Args...)> {
  std::unique_ptr<details::i_uf_impl<R(Args...)>> pimpl;
  unique_function(unique_function&&)=default;
  unique_function& operator=(unique_function&&)=default;
  unique_function()=default;
  template<class F, class=std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_same<std::decay_t<F>, unique_function>
    && ( std::is_convertible<std::result_of_t< F(Args...) >, R >{}
      || std::is_same< R, void >{} )
  >>
  unique_function(F&& f):pimpl(
    new details::uf_impl<R(Args...), std::decay_t<F>>{std::forward<F>(f)}
  ) {}
  // override deduction helper:
  unique_function(R(*pfun)(Args...)):pimpl(
    pfun?
      new details::uf_impl<R(Args...), R(*)(Args...)>{pfun}
    : nullptr
  ) {}
  // null case
  unique_function(nullptr_t):unique_function(){}
  explicit bool operator() const { return static_cast<bool>(pimpl); }
  R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return pimpl->invoke( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
```

which may or may not work, but should give you the gist.

Answer (score 2):

Because `y` gets destroyed:

```
void put(std::unique_ptr<Y> y)
{

    m_queue.push([&] {  // <== capturing y by-reference
        foo(std::move(y)); 
    });

    // <== y gets destroyed here
}
```

At the end of `put()`, `y` has already been cleaned up.

You'd want your functor to take ownership of `y`, which would ideally look something like:

```
[p = std::move(y)] {
    foo(std::move(p));
}
```

The lambda above has a member variable of type `unique_ptr<Y>`, so its copy constructor is implicitly deleted. But [func.wrap.func.con] stipulates that:

> ```
> template<class F> function(F f);
> template <class F, class A> function(allocator_arg_t, const A& a, F f);
> ```
>
> *Requires*: `F` shall be `CopyConstructible`.

so this is won't compile either.  Which leaves you somewhat stuck.

Comment: Can you explain the second part of your response please? i.e. the relevance of `std::function` needing to be copyable wrt to your example.

Comment: @ksl Added that explanation.